# Unable to fetch 'datetime' in correct format from Google sheet for Google chart on Google web apps

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I added Google line chart ([from here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)) on HTML page on Google web app and the data table comes from Google Sheets. Initially, line chart was accepting 'number' for x-axis but I changed it to 'datetime' and it accept date in "`new Date(yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm,ss)`"
But i am able to change the format of the date but chart is not working.

My problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62018515/google-line-chart-date-formatting), but this is my first time working with Google web app or JavaScript. So, i was unable to understand the solution.

Below is the sample data table:

| Date | SP1 | Sp2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/09/2021 00:02:34 | 2 | 3.5 |
| 02/09/2021 01:02:34 | 4 | 7 |
| 02/09/2021 02:02:34 | 10 | 14 |

Code.gs:

```js
function getTableDataQQ() {
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id').getSheetByName('August');
  const data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  const sheetname = ws.getSheetName();

  return data.map((r) => [
    Utilities.formatDate(
      new Date(r[0]),
      'GMT+0530',
      'yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss'
    ),
    parseInt(r[1]),
    parseInt(r[2]),
  ]);
}
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['line']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getData);

    function getData() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getTableDataQQ();
    }

    function drawChart(dataReturned) {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'Days');
        data.addColumn('number', 'SP1');
        data.addColumn('number', 'SP2');
        data.addColumn('number', 'SP3');


        data.addRows(dataReturned);


        var opt = {

            title: 'Text 1',
            subtitle: 'Text 2'

        };
        var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(opt));
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 1000px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>
```

I made changes in the original line chart script using this [YT tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRbR5HSZShA).
If add required data in the original script (like below) then the Line chart works, but I don't how to connect the original code with the Google sheet cause I follow the YT tutorial

Original Scrpt:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['line']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('datetime', 'Day');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
        data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

        data.addRows([
            [new Date(2021, 09, 01, 19, 02), 37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
            [new Date(2021, 09, 01, 19, 32), 30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
            [new Date(2021, 09, 01, 20, 02), 25.4, 57, 25.7],
            [new Date(2021, 02, 01, 20, 02, 00), 4.2, 6.2, 3.4]
        ]);

        var options = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
                subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
            },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    }
</script>
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current issue as follows.

- In your script, the value of column "A" is like `'2021,02,08,21,32,34'`. In this case, this cannot be directly used as the date scale.
- In your sample Spreadsheet, the data has 3 columns. But in your Javascript, 4 columns are used.
- About `data.addColumn('number', 'Days');`, from your sample Date values, `02/09/2021 00:02:34`, `02/09/2021 01:02:34` and `02/09/2021 02:02:34`, in this case, I thought that `timeofday` might be suitable.

When above issue was resolved from your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

In this case, please modify your Javascript as follows.

#### From:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Days');
data.addColumn('number', 'SP1');
data.addColumn('number', 'SP2');
data.addColumn('number', 'SP3');


data.addRows(dataReturned);
```

#### To:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Days');
data.addColumn('number', 'SP1');
data.addColumn('number', 'SP2');
var obj = dataReturned.map(([a, ...b]) => [a.split(",").slice(-3).map(e => Number(e)), ...b]);
data.addRows(obj);
```

Of, when you want to use `datetime`, you can also use the following modification.

#### To:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Days');
data.addColumn('number', 'SP1');
data.addColumn('number', 'SP2');
var obj = dataReturned.map(([a, ...b]) => [new Date(...a.split(",").map((e, i) => i == 1 ? Number(e) - 1 : e)), ...b]);
data.addRows(obj);
```

#### Reference:

- [Dates and Times](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Actually i am fetching data from 9 columns. Just for example i reduced it to 3. Can you please example what "a" and "b". As i mentioned before I just started working on App script with help of YT Tutorials. Thanks Please just spoon feed me.

Comment: @Gaurav K.M. Thank you for replying. About `Actually i am fetching data from 9 columns. Just for example i reduced it to 3. Can you please example what "a" and "b".`, I think that your `getTableDataQQ` has already retrieved 3 columns. So I cannot understand your replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. If you can do, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your new goal. I would like to think of the solution by correctly understand your new goal. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike for giving your time & effort.
I just want ti change `date` format in `getTableDataQQ`, so that Line chart would show "Date" on x-axis. But the `date` in `getTableDataQQ` is in `"dd/MM/yyyy,  HH:mm:ss"` format.
Like Below

    `[
    [02/09/2021 00:02:34, 4564, 11494],
    [02/09/2021 00:32:32, 2810, 6761],
    [02/09/2021 02:32:33, 1764, 4692]
    ]`

But Line Chart script reads date in 

    `[
    [new Date(2021, 09, 01, 00, 02, 34), 4564, 11494],
    [new Date(2021, 09, 01, 00, 32, 32), 2810, 6761],
    [new Date(2021, 09, 01, 02, 32, 33), 1764, 4692]
    ]`

Comment: ]
So, I tried changing the date format by using `"Utilities.formatDate"` (as you can see in my original question)
and also try concatenating `"new Date()"` like this:
`"new Date (" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(r[0]),'GMT+0530', 'yyyy, MM, dd, HH, mm, ss') + ")"` in `getTableDataQQ` function,. But nothing seems to be working for Line Chart.
Your above reply, could be the answer but due to lack of basic knowledge of javascript or appscript. I am unable to understand the solution.

Comment: Could you please use my assigned variable to demonstrate, what i need to do in the modified script in my **HTML** (please see original Question) or if you could just show me how can i connect **Original script** ([from here][1]) to google sheet with required date format .


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: @Gaurav K.M. Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, what are the sample input and output values? Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your new question. I apologize for this. But from your additional information, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, now I understood the initial solution you gave. I got confused due to this `(e, i) => i == 1 ? Number(e) - 1 : e)` line. So I did this `var obj = dataReturned.map(r => [new Date(r[0].slice(6,10),[0].slice(3,5),...), parseInt(r[1]),parseInt(r[2])` and `datetime` worked for me. Thank you so much for you help Tanaike.